# Why doesn't this update the screen after it is fired?

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks, task

I am scheduling a simple task that should update a text field in 4 seconds.

However everytime this is called the activity pauses and does not show the value in the text field until I restart the activity.

```
 private void showDelayedValue() {

    Runnable longRunningTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

        int randomVal = randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(30 - -10) - 10; //random number between -10 and 30
        String randomValStr = Integer.toString(randomVal);

            Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),
                "FIRED startScheduler: " + randomValStr);

        theFieldOnScreenTV.setText(randomTempStr);

        }
    };
    //show the value in 2 seconds
    scheduledTaskExecutor.schedule(longRunningTask, 4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }
```

The log shows:

```
FIRED startScheduler: 4
```

but does not update the `TextView theFieldOnScreenTV`

Instead  `onPause` is called right after `Fired startScheduler:` is displayed in LogCat.

Many thanks!

EDIT:

This worked for me following Alex' approach:

```
private void showDelayedValue() {
    int randomX = randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(30 - -10) - 10; 
    final String randomXStr = Integer.toString(randomX);
    final Runnable updateFieldR = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        theFieldOnScreenTV.setText(randomXStr);
        }
    };

    Runnable longRunningTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        theFieldOnScreenTV.post(updateFieldR);

        }
    };
    scheduledTaskExecutor.schedule(longRunningTask, 4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }
```

Comment: Try calling theFieldOnScreenTV.invalidate(); after setText();.

Comment: I did, it did not help thank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
theFieldOnScreenTV.setText(randomTempStr);
```

try

```
theFieldOnScreenTV.post(new Runnable() { theFieldOnScreenTV.setText(randomTempStr); } );
```

Comment: Thanks. Super idea! The suggested code did not work, I got the error taht Runnable needs to implement run, this is why I implemented it the way shown in the edit above - following your idea about using runnable for update the textview - which solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Have a try using Handlers.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {

theFieldOnScreenTV.setText(randomTempStr);          
    }
});
```

Comment: handler used correctly would work - but is more complicated - thanks!